# Is there a way to write styling within the body of HTML using PHP to *Move* it

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, parsing

I was just wondering if there was a way to write CSS styling within the body, to pull it into the head tag using some php.?

... not necessarily inline styling

... Is there a way to run the php before the HTML head tag is parsed?

**I assumed this would be possible:**

1. write some style in the body:

   ```
   <body>
     <div class="moveCSS">
       <style type="text/css">
         #frog
         {
         font-color: green;
         }
       </style>
     </div>
   <p class="frog">Frog's are stereotypically documented as being 'green' in colour, when in actual fact are often very different depending on their environmental habitat!</p>
   </body>
   ```
2. In the head write something similar to this:

   ```
   <head>
     <?php
       function getElementsByClassName(\DOMDocument $DOMDocument, $ClassName)
       {
         $Elements = $DOMDocument->getElementsByTagName("moveCSS");
         $Matched = array();

         for($i=0;$i<$Elements->length;$i++)
         {

           if($Elements->item($i)->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->nodeValue == $ClassName)
           {
             $Matched[]=$Elements->item($i);
           }
         }
         return $Matched;
       }
   ?>
   </head>
   ```

   (Snippet of PHP code reference: [Link to Page](http://lampcms.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/getelementsbyclassname-in-php.html#847667880223375724) ...FYI: I'm sure variable names need to start with a lowercase alphabetical char in PHP)

If this were possible, It would allow me to write better CSS into CMS articles, avoiding the requirement to access the CSS files and to manually add custom entries.
The single class name of 'moveCSS' would enforce that anything written within a 'moveCSS' div will be included in the head. Making my work more malleable.

Answer (score -1):

No, instead write the css in original document and load it with JavaScript wherever required or completely write inline if css is not too complex.

Comment: Can you provide me with some logic to your answer please.

It would help if you explained 'Why' it wouldn't accept a PHP script?...


I will be using this in a Joomla editor environment, so the <head> tag cannot be reached from the admin view (unless you head to templates or the root directory (FTP))

Comment: If you do not have the answer please leave a comment. ...Writing an answer is meant to provide a solution to the matter. I was looking for a way to write css in the head so that advanced features can be written 'inline' aka :hover or :after .... content:something;.

Comment: Well if you would have looked carefully, I didn't had enough reputation that time to comment.
Thank you for down voting.

Comment: You haven't answered my question, just given an alternative view, which doesn't solve my problem. I've had a thought that: I'm thinking it would be possible to run a PHP script that automatically adds the 'X string' to the .css file and reloads the page... thus allowing for css to be added within the body...